# Dynamic Server-Side Mobile Template - Does Anything Exist?

Tags: javascript, templates, rest, template-engine, mustache

I'm wondering if I could get some opinions on whether this development project would be new and useful, or if it has already been done before.

I've been researching an idea that I have to create a premade solution for a "Dynamic Server-Side Mobile Template" solution. In my previous job I was tasked with maintaining multiple mobile clients, each of them having a custom UI skin. Normally this ends up requiring a lot of developer time when clients request UI changes or updates. My goal is to design a system that requires minimal developer input and allows designers complete control over the UI, including:

- Ability to update content any time
- Version control (push new template designs to client, roll-back to previous versions)
- No need for developer input for design changes

What I'm brainstorming is a server side service module which is capable of providing templates on demand using RESTFul web services. The server would provide an HTML input function that would decompose any HTML page to a component tree. The component tree would then be saved to the database and displayed for confirmation & editing.

The server would be responsible for:

- Decomposing any HTML page into its' template components

  - 3rd party files such a JS, CSS referenced by path
- Displaying HTML component tree for debuging and editing purposes
- Saving template component details in the database with versioning
- Providing template on demand (via JSON or XML) through RESTFul API

The client could be written using [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) and easily ported to the various mobile devices using the various offshoots (iOS, Android, etc). This thin client would simply send a request to the configured URI designated by the server. The URI would return all template information using mustache syntax, and this would be used to dynamically build the UI on demand. The client could also save the UI configuration and reload only when a new version is released.

To summarize, the client would be responsible for:

- Requesting template data (JSON or XML) from predefined URL
- Rendering template using mustache, assuming version not already saved.

I would love to start this as an open source project if the demand or need is there, and I'm not re-inventing the wheel. So far I've found similar concepts but none seem to be fully dynamic.